An alternative solution to the problem of sitting non-hostile ambassadors on a round table
I'm currently reading Problem-Solving strategies by Arthur Engel and came across the following question:

$2n$ ambassadors are invited to a banquet. Every ambassador has at most $n−1$
enemies. Prove that the ambassadors can be seated around a round table, so that
nobody sits next to an enemy.

A rather long proof is given in the book, but I think that the solution is rather simple. Here's my proof:
Consider a certain configuration of ambassadors on the round table. Consider an arbitrary ambassador (let's call him $A$). If $n\geq 2$, he will have two neighbours. For the configuration to be valid, these neighbours can't be enemies of $A$. Additionally, since you cannot be your own enemy, an additional spot (your own spot) cannot be assumed by an enemy. Since there are $2n$ ambassadors, $2n-3$ spots remain on the round table. $A$ can have a maximum of $n-1$ enemies. Now, let's stick with the case where $n\geq 2$. We can write this as $2n - n\geq 2$. Further, $2n - n \geq -1 + 3$. Finally, $2n - 3\geq n-1$. Thus, we've shown that the $n-1$ enemies can be fitted in the $2n-3$ spots and we're done.
Handling the case where $n = 1$ is also easy.
So, is this proof valid?

You've only shown the existence of configuration where one particular ambassador $A$ isn't seated next to their enemies. You'd have to continue from there once $A$ and $A$'s enemies (or two of $A$'s friends next to $A$) are seated to give seats to the other ambassadors.
One way to do this is to consider the "non-enemy graph" of the ambassadors and use Dirac's theorem on the existence of a Hamilton cycle when each vertex degree is larger than half the size of the graph. Was this the book's proof?

yes, that's correct. I thought that since the choice of the ambassador was arbitrary, I could extend my line of reasoning to all $2n$ ambassadors
